# Changing default address in fuse osgi for web service

Tags: cxf, fuseesb

By default fuse ESB gives  an end point url leading with cxf. For example if i have

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="HTTPEndpoint"
    implementor="org.fusesource.example.PersonImpl"
    address="/PersonServiceCF"/>
```

End point configured in a spring bean, after deploying it as bundle, fuse will publish this end point as  `http://localhost:8181/cxf/PersonServiceCF?wsdl`

Now i wanted to change the default leading url cxf to some thing else xyz.  It should look like 
`http://localhost:8181/xyz/PersonServiceCF?wsdl` . How can I do it, I googled alot, but could not find the configuration document. Any hint is really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/smx5/trunk/examples/cxf/cxf-ws-security-osgi/README.txt) documentation:

> **Changing /cxf servlet alias**
>
> By default CXF Servlet is assigned a '/cxf' alias. You can change it in a couple of ways:
>
> a. Add org.apache.cxf.osgi.cfg to the /etc directory and set the 'org.apache.cxf.servlet.context' property, for example:
>
> ```
>  org.apache.cxf.servlet.context=/custom
> ```
>
> b. Use shell config commands, for example :
>
> ```
>  config:edit org.apache.cxf.osgi   
>  config:propset org.apache.cxf.servlet.context /super
>  config:update
> ```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this programatically? In my use case I need to run two cxf buses... any ideas?